# Restar dos fechas en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una tabla, estas dos tablas tienen dos fechas una de inicio y otra de fin, necesito restar la fecha fin con la fecha de inicio para que esta me arroje los días y me agregue el resultado en un campo automáticamente.

**TABLA** 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CAMPOS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: Un trigger pero no me funciona llevo toda la mañana investigando :(

Comment: ya trataste de usar `DATEDIFF()` ? mira esto https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: No no he usado DATEDIFF muchas gracias, voy a seguir intentando entonces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes hacer uso de la función `DATEDIFF()`, con un ejercicio como el siguiente te arrojara el numero de dias que hay entre dos fechas

```
declare @FechaInicial Date = '01/05/2019'
declare @Fechafinal Date = '15/05/2019'

select DATEDIFF (DAY, @FechaInicial , @Fechafinal )  as resultado
```

si lo que deseas hacer es insertar ese valor en una tabla de tu db, lo que puedes hacer es sencillamente encapsular ese valor en una variable e insertarlo en el campo de tu tabla, acá un ejercicio para que te guies

```
declare @FechaInicial Date = '01/05/2019'
declare @Fechafinal Date = '15/05/2019'

BEGIN
        BEGIN
            CREATE TABLE #Result(
            Valor int
            )
        END

        declare @Valor int
        set @Valor = DATEDIFF (DAY, @FechaInicial , @Fechafinal )

        insert into #Result
        select @Valor

END
```

espero poder orientarte